# getting scheduling error when forwarding s3 object to flask response

Tags: python-3.x, flask, amazon-s3

I'm using the following to pull a data file from an s3 compliant server:

```py
    try:
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        client.download_fileobj(project_id, path, buf)
        body = buf.getvalue().decode("utf-8")

    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if defaultValue is not None:
            return defaultValue
        else:
            raise S3Error(project_id, path, e) from e
    else:
        return body
```

The code generates this error:

```py
RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown
```

In general, I'm simply trying to read an `s3`-compliant file into the body of a response object.  The caller of the above snippet is as follows:

```py
        data = read_file(project_id, f"{PATH}/data.csv")
        response = Response(
            data,
            mimetype="text/csv",
            headers=[
                ("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8"),
                ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=data.csv")
            ],
            direct_passthrough=True
        )
```

Playing with the code, if I don't get a runtime error, the request hangs in that I don't get a returned response.

Thank you to anyone with guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how generic this answer will be, however, the combination of using `boto` to access the digital ocean version of the s3 implementation does not "strictly" permit using an object key that starts with `/`.  Once I removed the offending leading character, the files downloaded as expected.

I base the `boto` specificity on the fact that I was able to read the files using a Haskell's `amazonka`.